# hibernate - Model of Classes

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new in hibernate and I want to solve some doubt. At first, I've been searching for some kind of entity that I want to understand how do I map my entity, but I didnt find nothing so "comum" and simple to understand and I need help with this.

I have a class named "client" and another called "adress" and other called "company", Client has a list of adress, and company just once, but how do I map this?

I say, when use @manytoone (mapped by) or other kind?

My class CLIENT:

```
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //Adress
    private List<Adress> adress;
}
```

My Class Adress:

```
@Entity
public class Adress{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String pobox;
}
```

My Class Company:

```
@Entity
public class Company{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    //Adress
    private Adress adress;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An address is usually one to one. That is, a company would not share an address with another company, would it? So you can try:

```
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
  private Adress address;
```

Comment: I tested and its right, I didnt put the JoinColumn and get right